# Facebook/Workplace Graph API: Error posting image to album

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

Several years ago I wrote an app that watches a file share for incoming PDFs, extracts all images from the PDF, creates an album on a Workplace page, and posts the images to that album. This has been working fine for years, but suddenly, on May 24th, it started failing with a 500 Internal Server Error when POSTing the images. Has there been some kind of change to the Graph API that can explain this? I'm basically POSTing (using WebClient.UploadFile) to https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN. According to the Access Token Debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ my app has the following Workplace Integration Permissions: `read_group, write_group, link_unfurling`. Any and all hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may be caused by a known issue: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/422557782692044/ Even though this refers to endpoint {groupId}/photos, according to this thread https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1167214814122516/?join_id=f376b4bd2da9ff8, failing POSTs to {albumId}/photos are caused by the same issue. Also, the reported Last Known Working Date of May 23 2022 fits perfectly with our experiences.